# spawn EACCES error with chromedriver when running Nightwatch.js tests via Jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I am trying to run Nightwatch.js tests via Jenkins and I am getting this specific error:

```
Error: spawn chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe EACCES
```

This is my current Nightwatch.conf.js configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  "src_folders": ["tests"],
  "webdriver": {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": "chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe",
    "port": 9515
  },
```

My chromedriver_win32 folder only contains:

```
chromedriver.exe
```

Any help is appreciated!

I have already tried changing the chromedriver path in the Nightwatch.conf.js to make sure that it is correctly pointing to the chromedriver.exe folder, but still nothing resolved.

Comment: The machine (Jenkins agent) where your tests run is  Windows OS and same version  Chrome as your local is installed on it?